# How to read ros::Publisher pub

Tags: roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please, help me to correctly read some code to have more understanding of the basics of ROS. I understand that `#include<ros.h>` is to include the cpp library of ROS

How should I read this `ros::Publisher pub`?

Is it make an object named pub of the class Publisher defined in the namespace ros or what?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251843/how-to-read-ros::publisher-pub/) by [Biomacs](https://answers.ros.org/users/25467/biomacs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-01-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2017-01-13**:
This is the wrong place to ask this kind of questions. Your question is related to the basic of C++. I suggest to start with C++ and then go to ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it make an object named pub of the class Publisher defined in the namespace ros or what?

Basically, yes (and to be precise, the object is created *on the stack*), but as @rastaxe wrote: please follow a C++ tutorial or two and *then* start working with `roscpp`. This is really a C++ question, and I would not want to be learning C++ *and* ROS at the same time.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-01-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1